# how can i save input data in File

Tags: java, file

I try to make a sign-up form but I have some problem with saving data using File.
I don't know what is the problem. what should I do?

I added an action listener and then try this to save input of text fields

```
 public void saveData() {
    if (textField == nameField) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt"));
            bw.write(nameField.getText());
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and then I try this

[image]

Comment: What are those problems you speak of?

Comment: what is the purpose of `textField == nameField`?

Comment: Are you trying to compare the Strings with `==`?

Comment: @csalmhof no i just want to say if the source was nameField (nameField is a textfield),save the input that user says.i used to put it in action listener and action performed but when it didn't work i try this.

Comment: @daniu it doesn't save anything.that's the problem.

Comment: @f1sh first i used action performed `if (e.getSource()==nameField)` to save nameField input in file and when it didn't work i try this

Comment: Please post the entire file. There is a good possibility this code block is never even reached.

Answer (score 0):

Write the whole path of the file instead of just data.txt.
It might help.

Answer (score 0):

What is in the data.txt. Maybe that is blank ? Check it.